# django backend doesn't support absolute paths

Tags: django, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am working Crop Images in a Django Application

using this tutorial [Crop Images in Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/02/how-to-crop-images-in-a-django-application.html)

Myform:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
x = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
y = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
width = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
height = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
primaryphoto = forms.ImageField(required=False,
                                error_messages={'invalid': _("Image files only")}, widget=forms.FileInput)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['primaryphoto', 'x', 'y', 'width', 'height',]


def save(self):
    user = super(UploadImageForm, self).save()
    x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
    y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
    w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
    h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

    image = Image.open(user.primaryphoto)
    cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y))
    resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)

    return user
```

myview:

```
def upload_image(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/profile')
else:
    form = UploadImageForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, 'student/uploadimageform.html', {'form': form})
```

storage_backend.py:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

However, when I uploaded it to run on AWS, I got the error message that the `backend does not support absolute paths (in reference to primaryphoto.path in the form where the photo is cropped)`. I was wondering what I have to change to get it working with S3. I've found some resources that say change primaryphoto.path to primaryphoto.name, but that hasn't worked for me. I was wondering if you had any recommendations to solve this problem?

Here Image is uploaded to S3 Bucket but issue is throwing above error. Please help me anyone. Thanks in advance ...

Edit answer:

```
    def save(self):
    user = super(UploadImageForm, self).save()
    x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
    y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
    w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
    h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')
    try:
        image = Image.open(user.primaryphoto)
        cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y))
        resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)
    except:
        pass

    return user
```

Here issue is throwing error but image is uploading locally and S3 bucket properly ... for handling path error i am using try, except block

Comment: you need to authenticate yourself with your `ACCESS_ID` and `ACCESS_KEY` to access these files. `photo.path` will never work with AWS

Comment: @Lemayzeur I did everything image is uploading S3 bucket also issue is while uploading throwing This backend doesn't support absolute paths. this error, image absolutely uploading fine and locally no issue, issue is production only

Comment: Instead os resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)  path what should i do @Lemayzeur

Comment: The issue will actually happen only in production since static files in production are on AWS! If you want the path you can concatenate `settings.AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION` to your `filename`

Comment: @Lemayzeur can you explain more how can i use aws path this line resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)  instead of path should i mention aws path

Comment: I am using my url.py file + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) this, should i change this path to aws path

Comment: Ok, I am gonna try to provide an answer, be clear with this line `resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)` what do you want to do? what your expectation after cropping the image.

Comment: here i am redirecting profile page after uploading image issue is uploading image properly, but showing error i am not sure how can i handle this error, here i want to handle this exception before redirecting another page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182070/discussion-between-somesh-and-lemayzeur).

Comment: I am not sure try , except block correct idea i don't have choice here because i did this back end everything working fine

Answer (score 2):

For me default.storage.write() did not work, image.save() did not work, this one worked. See this code if anyone is still interested. I apologize for the indentation. My project was using Cloudinary and Django small project.

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage    

def save(self, *args, **kargs):
super(User, self).save(*args, **kargs)
# After save, read the file
image_read = storage.open(self.profile_image.name, "r")
image = Image.open(image_read)
    if image.height > 200 or image.width > 200:
       size = 200, 200
    
      # Create a buffer to hold the bytes
       imageBuffer = BytesIO()

      # Resize  
       image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

      # Save the image as jpeg to the buffer
       image.save(imageBuffer, image.format)

      # Check whether it is resized
       image.show()

      # Save the modified image
       user = User.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
       user.profile_image.save(self.profile_image.name, ContentFile(imageBuffer.getvalue()))

       image_read = storage.open(user.profile_image.name, "r")
       image = Image.open(image_read)
       image.show()

    image_read.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead.

I don't test it, but some explanations will be good: We convert the image into string buffer in order to create a Django [`InMemoryUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile) with the cropped image. In this case, we don't use `path`. Try it and let me know you face any other errors.

```
import os
from io import BytesIO as StringIO # python3
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

def save(self):
    user = super(UploadImageForm, self).save()
    x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
    y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
    w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
    h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

    image = Image.open(user.primaryphoto)
    cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y))
    resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    filename = os.path.splitext(resized_image.name)[0] 

    output = StringIO()
    resized_image.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
    output.seek(0) #Change the stream position to the given byte offset.


    new_image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField',\
        "%s.jpg" % filename , 'image/jpeg', output.__sizeof__(), None)

    user.primaryphoto = new_image
    user.save()

    return user
```

Comment: i am getting this error  'Image' object has no attribute 'name' in this line  filename = os.path.splitext(resized_image.name)[0]

Comment: add this `print(type(resized_image),dir(resized_image))`  before, and show me the output

Comment: try this it should work `filename = os.path.splitext(resized_image.filename)[0]`

Comment: Sorry @Lemayzeur i am troubling you. Image is uploading without resizing but same issue 'Image' object has no attribute 'filename'

Comment: add this print(type(resized_image),dir(resized_image)) before, and show me the output

Comment: can you see above i am updating answer here issue is path only everything working file like uploading image in S3 bucket and locally i am wasting lot of time to this now i am handling back end path error using try, except block Thank you so much you valuable support

Comment: print(cropped_image)

<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=250x251 at 0x5C5A430>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182076/discussion-between-somesh-and-lemayzeur).

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me. Just replace the save() method in your form.

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

      def save(self):
            user = super(UploadImageForm, self).save()
            x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
            y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
            w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
            h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

            image = Image.open(user.primaryphoto)
            cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y))
            resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            fh = storage.open(user.primaryphoto.name, "w")
            picture_format = 'png'
            resized_image.save(fh, picture_format)
            fh.close()        
            resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)
            return user
```

Comment: This answer is what helped me greatly! However, there is a slight error. You need to remove the very last line above 'return user'. That is, remove this line: "resized_image.save(user.primaryphoto.path)". It seems to be a mistake that it was left in there.

Answer (score 1):

For those redirected here from google, here's code tested and working on aws based on answers from @Alexandar Dimitro and other comments on this page.

```
  from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

  def save(self):
        user = super(UploadImageForm, self).save()
        x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
        y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
        w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
        h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

        image = Image.open(user.primaryphoto)
        cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y))
        resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        fh = storage.open(user.primaryphoto.name, "wb")
        picture_format = 'png'
        resized_image.save(fh, picture_format)
        fh.close()        
        return user
```